# Надо ли бороться с повтором корня

Tags: лексика

"Может помочь", "некоторые из которых" - всегда ли необходимо искать синонимы или пусть себе живут парочкой?

> В 12:00 закроется большинство церквей, некоторые из которых богаче, чем
>   собрания большинства наших музеев.
>
> ---
>
> ...Устраивать как многочисленные частные, так и общедоступные термы
>   (некоторые из которых вмещали более трех тысяч человек одновременно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С "*некоторыми*" надо бороться, во избежание каламбуроподобных созвучий в серьёзном тексте. Проблемы бывают от навязчивой звуковой корреляции, а не от родственности по корню: в "может помочь" её можно заметить (если она есть) разве что при дотошном учебном разборе, при пользовании же языком этим на ходу всё равно не занимаются.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того, где. Если речь идёт о разговорной речи, то некоторые повторения допустимы. Однако, если вы слишком часто будете повторяться, то это может звучать глупо и в таких случаях собеседник будет считать вас стилистически неграмотным.
Если же вы пишете сочинение или научную работу, то лучше стараться совсем избегать лексического повтора.
Решить проблему поможет подбор синонимов или совсем исключить это выражение.

В данном случае желательно избежать повторов хотя бы в одном абзаце.

Comment: "Где" у меня приведено в пояснении к вопросу.

Comment: В данном случае желательно избежать повторов хотя бы в одном абзаце.